# Unexpected results from compute shader after call to dispatch and glMemoryBarrier

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, compute-shader

I am trying to set up a compute shader (first time I do this).
And would like to see some simple results, computed by the shader.
To do this I have a `uniform imageBuffer`, which the shader code reads from, using `imageLoad`. Then it increments the value in the shader by `1`. Finally it stores the changed value via `imageStore`.

Then, to verify the results, in the c++ side I map the buffer to a local array using `glMapBufferRange` and print what's inside.

With this setup, I would expect all fields of the buffer to have been incremented by 1, per invocation of the compute shader.

But I observe the increment only for each third invocation of the shader. For the other two I observe the old value from the prior iteration.

For `glMemoryBarrier` I have attempted to use

```
GL_SHADER_IMAGE_ACCESS_BARRIER_BIT
GL_CLIENT_MAPPED_BUFFER_BARRIER_BIT
GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS
```

But all options show the same wrong result.

Is there anything obvious that I'm missing?
I am dimly aware that the GLSL functions `imageLoad/Store` operate 'memory-incoherently', but shouldn't the CPU-side call to `glMemoryBarrier` after the dispatch take care of making all increments visible?

i.e. the output for a specific buffer index, looks like this:

```
val: 0
val: 0
val: 1

val: 1
val: 1
val: 2

val: 2
val: 2
val: 3
...
```

my compute shader looks like this

```
#version 430 core

layout (local_size_x = 1024) in;
layout (rgba32f, binding = 0) uniform imageBuffer position_buffer;

void main(void)
{
  int index = int(gl_GlobalInvocationID.x);

  vec4 u_curr_vec = imageLoad(position_buffer, index);

  barrier();
  
  u_curr_vec.x += 1;
    
  imageStore(position_buffer, index, u_curr_vec);
}
```

The buffer image is instantiated like so:

```
glGenTextures(1, tbo_name_union_instance.tbos);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, tbo_name_union_instance.tbos[0]);
glTexBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, GL_RGBA32F, buffer_name_union_instance.buffers[0]);
```

and then, after shader activation, it is bound:

```
glBindImageTexture(0, tbo_name_union_instance.tbo_pair_name.position_tbo, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_READ_WRITE, GL_RGBA32F);
```

Comment: And what does your shader look like?

Comment: @NicolBolas I've added the shader code above.

Comment: And what about the buffer-image? Does it really use the RGBA32F format? Did you bind it with `glBindImageTexture` with that format?

Comment: @NicolBolas yes, I added the code again above.

Comment: @NicolBolas
I think I found the problem: I am using glDrawArrays.

From the documentation:

 // Vertex attributes that are modified by glDrawArrays have an unspecified value after glDrawArrays returns.

"The call to glDrawArrays must therefore change the buffer content, resulting in the above behavior."